# htaccess rewrite rule from folder to folder with querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am looking to include a rewrite rule for the following but can't seem to get it to work. I don't want to pass any query string in but I need to add one to the rule.

I want this URL:

```
https://example.co.uk/vehicles/
```

to point to:

```
https://example.co.uk/search-results/?category=1
```

but keep the first URL in the address bar. 
I need to pass in a variable called category with a value.

I tried the following but it didn't work for me:

```
rewriterule ^vehicles/$ search-results/?category=1 [NC, L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ad/(.*/)?([0-9]+)$ view-ad/?ad=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^vehicles/$ search-results/?category=1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: "didn't work" - please be more specific. What happened exactly? The directive you posted above would result in a 500 Internal Server Error - because you have an erroneous _space_ in the _flags_ argument.

Comment: I'm using my own server and website. The page loads but not pulling the querystring variable through.

Comment: Amended to include the .htaccess file above

Comment: I'm not sure. Someone else helped me with them.

Comment: The page loads but with no querystring

Comment: I managed to solve it. It was due to an Ajax load on the page. The rewrite was causing the Ajax page to not load because it didn't have the full url in the url of the Ajax call. Now that it works is it possible to have another rewrite rule that does this https://domain.co.uk/vehicles/?something=1 and rewrite to https://domain.co.uk/vehicles/?category=1&appendsomething=1 but only display https://domain.co.uk/vehicles/

Answer (score 0):

> I managed to solve it. It was due to an Ajax load on the page.

Glad you solved your initial query, however, the following two directives in your posted `.htaccess` file will break your site, so presumably, these have already been removed?

> ```
> RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
> ```

The first directive simply blocks all access to your site, returning a 403 Forbidden response. And the second directive will result in a redirect loop.

> Now that it works is it possible to have another rewrite rule that does this `https://example.co.uk/vehicles/?something=1` and rewrite to `https://example.co.uk/vehicles/?category=1&appendsomething=1` but only display `https://example.co.uk/vehicles/`

I assume you mean `https://example.co.uk/search-results/?category=1&something=1` (as opposed to `/vehicles/`) - where `something=1` is *appended* on the end of the query string?

You wouldn't be able to make this "display as `https://example.co.uk/vehicles/`" - as this would *conflict* with your existing (working) directive.

However, you could potentially modify your existing directive to handle requests for `/?something=1` and pass this through to the *substitution*. This would simply require the addition of the `QSA` flag (Query String Append). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^vehicles/$ search-results/?category=1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The `QSA` flag results in the query string from the request being appended to the end of the query string specified in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

---

**UPDATE:** To redirect HTTP to HTTPS, you would need something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

Note the preceding `RewriteCond` directive - this ensures that only HTTP requests are redirected, not *everything* (HTTP and HTTPS), so avoiding a redirect loop. Ultimately this should also be a 301 (permanent) redirect, so you should change `R` to `R=301`, but only when you are sure it's working OK.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1 [R,L]    I thought this line just redirects any http to https. All I want is to replace http with https.

Comment: That line by itself would redirect _everything_ (both HTTP _and_ HTTPS) so you would get a redirect loop (as it would keep on issuing a redirecting back to itself). You need a _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) that prevents HTTPS requests being redirected. I've updated my answer. (If the above was not resulting in a redirect loop - since you make no mention of this(?) then it can't be getting processed at all?!)